# REGEX: replace a specific character after the appearence of another character in string

Tags: regex, vim

i have this string:
owl:Class rdf:about="#other important people"

i want with help of vim regex to replace the space with _ but only after the word starting with #.

I mean i want finally: 
owl:Class rdf:about="#other_important_people"

sorry for my poor grammar

Answer (score 2):

```
:s/\(#[^"]*\)\@<= /_/g
```

Comment: Will this only replace the first space after the #