# replace all instances of one character after a specific character in a string

Tags: regex, datetime, replace

I hate to ask another "how do you do this with regex" question on here...there seem to be a lot of them. But, I am struggling with this.

I am working in C#, and I need to correct a datetime string before I convert it from a string to a DateTime datatype variable. My string looks like this:

2012-01-24T17-52-08Z

I need to replace the "-" characters that occur after the "T" with colons, so it will look like this:

2012-01-24T17:52:08Z

I have tried to adapt the code from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468972/regex-replace-a-specific-character-after-the-appearence-of-another-character-in) but, to no avail. I have been using [this wonderful tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to try to get this working.

I know this will be simple to someone who regularly works with RegEx but, I work with it so rarely that I forget most of what I learned before I get a chance to use it again.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: If you expect a C♯ answer, you should have a C♯ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try matching with `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})Z`

and replacing with `$1:$2:$3Z`

Comment: Thanks! That works. I was thinking about it the wrong way. Thanks very much.